# S3 like routing rules in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to achieve  something like this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-websiteconfiguration-routingrules-redirectrule.html with GCS?

Basically, if there is a 403/404 from my bucket I want to serve the content from a file appending `#/` to the key. See https://github.com/ember-cli-deploy/ember-cli-deploy-s3-index#without-cloudfront

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Website Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration#step4). This allows you to specify 404 and 403 pages.

Comment: thanks... I managed to achieve want I wanted with the error page but is not exactly the same as s3 redirect rules (since the response will be a 404 even though it serves the page I want).